# Parse child of XML (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I know this is very simple question but how I can parse child of xml item?

I have WebUrl, but I need Description and Url.

This is my XML File :

```
<d:WebURL m:type="SP.FieldUrlValue">
    <d:Description>Google</d:Description>
    <d:Url>http://google.com</d:Url>
</d:WebURL>
<d:PublishingStartDate m:null="true"/>
<d:PublishingExpirationDate m:null="true">
```

This is my JS code :

```
function takeresult() {   
    var myurl = "";
    var executor = new CE.RequestExecutor();
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: itemsUrl,
        method: "GET",
        success: myresult,
        error: error
    }); 
}

function myresult(data) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
    var resultat = jsonObject.d.results;
    $(resultat).each(function(){
        var weburl = $(this)[0].WebURL;
        var description = ??
    });
}
```

Comment: You do realise that JSON and XML are different beasts

Comment: Yes I know, but here I need to find a way how just to show the description.

Comment: So why (Javascript one assumes) code is using JSON.parse?

Answer (score 2):

since you're using jQuery already, and I'm assuming your server is returning XML.

```
function myresult(data) {
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.body);
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $description = $xml.find( "description" );
    alert($description.text());
}
```